# PHP and large CSV files

Tags: php, csv, notorm

I was using a library called parsecsv.lib.php to read in csv files. However the files have grown in size, to about 30MB. This library tries to load the entire contents of the csv into an array, which is turning into arrays with over 100,000 elements. This is obviously no good, so i have rolled out my own solution, which is below:

```
private static function _get2DArrayFromCsvAndSave($file, $delimiter, $enclosure, $table)
{
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);
    if (($fp = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $headers = fgetcsv($fp, 0, $delimiter, $enclosure);
        while (($row = fgetcsv($fp, 0, $delimiter, $enclosure)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $data = array();
            foreach ($headers as $i => $col)
            {
                $data[$col] = $row[$i];
            }
            self::_save($table, $data);
            echo "*";
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

This is reading in one row at a time and saving with keys as headers and then saving.

My question is would i get any speed increase if i chunked the amount of data i am feeding to my save method. Right now it is only one array at a time, but i could feed it an array of arrays and save them.
I am just not sure if there any advantages to chunking the data. Anyone with experience have any insight

Here is the save method:

```
private static function _save($table, $data)
{
    $save = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $key = '`'.strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $key)).'`';
        // this sets the primary key for NotORM's insert_update method
        if ($i == 0)
            $id = $key;
        $i++;            
        $save[$key] = trim($value);            
    }
    self::$db->$table->insert_update(
            array($id => $save[$id]),
            $save,
            array());
}
```

Comment: If you wrap the saved chunks in a transaction or if notorm allows for multiple inserts in a single statement then chunking and saving will show a performance pickup.

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you not using `LOAD DATA INFILE`?

Comment: I had never heard of it until now. This program goes through about 30 different csvs of varying sizes, all with different headers and saves to the appropriate table, using the keys as column names. Out of curiosity how much faster would that be. And what happens on duplicates, Here you can see i do an insert_update, on update i just blow it off. These cvs contain data with duplicate primary keys. Thanks